# how to call a function defined in another cg shader file

Tags: shader, cg

If i define a function in a cg shader file and I want to call it in another cg shader file. Can I do this just like glsl? If I can implement it in this way, then how to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use #include in Cg.

I assume you mean to call a *function,* not a shader...

Comment: you mean if I define a function void test() in test.cg, then in another cg shader file, I should use #include"test.cg" to use it? I have tried this, but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: That's exactly how all the canonical #include functions work, yes. See http://developer.download.nvidia.com/shaderlibrary/webpages/shader_library.html

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your help. It didn't work because I used a global variable defined in another file, nothing to do with cg.